# How to connect IEC cable to the output of a Yokogawa WT310 power meter

Tags: power, measurement, wiring, cables

I am using a Yokogawa WT310 power meter. Its back side looks like this.
[image]

[image]

I want to use it to know the power an equipment is drawing out of the wall outlet.
Going into this meter, I obviously will use the C14 to lower right corner.

But for coming out of this meter, how should I split the three cables inside an IEC cable (with C13 end)?

Comment: What does the manual for the instrument say?

Comment: Not much unfortunately, actually I answered the question, but the problem is the diagram suggests that the terminals are single ended, if they are that would really complicate things.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I'm not sure why you deleted your answer.

Comment: Because there isn't a good way to tell if the terminals are single ended or differential by the diagram in the manual, if you were to connect a hot to ground (via the terminals) inside the unit, you'd blow a breaker

Answer (score 1):

The C14 in the lower right corner is for instrument power only. If you want to measure power you need to use both current and voltage terminals (both 2 and 1 in the diagram above)

[image]
Source: https://cdn.tmi.yokogawa.com/IMWT310-01EN.pdf

You won't be using an IEC cable in the normal way, you'll be building your own (or buying them, but I don't think they exist) with (hopefully with terminal lugs that can crimp on, these can be found in automotive and hardware stores). If I were doing this, I would take a C14 cable and cut it in half strip the ends, insert terminal lugs in the middle for the current on the hot line.

And I would get some high voltage banana connectors (which the unit probably comes with) and clip them to the hot and neutral lines. Realize that 120VAC or 220VAC are dangerous and need to be properly insulated when building the cable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ4SX7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Make sure the terminals of the current input and voltage input are not connected to the ground of the unit, do this with an ohmmeter. It isn't apparent from the diagrams that the current and voltage input are not grounded on one side (they shouldn't be, but the diagram in the manual could indicate that they are, the documentation is terrible).

Answer (score 0):

The C14 is just to power and ground the instrument, is todes not pass power from this connectro to the appliance. a separate connection is needed for the appliance power.

section 2.9 of the manual seems to cover everything.

https://web-material3.yokogawa.com/IMWT310-02EN.pdf

As this is power measurement quipment and not a consumer appliance the safety standards are somewhat relaxed (and thus the amount of care needed is increased)

If you are worried about electric shockvfrom the curren terminals you can use a current transformer for the current input.

you should definately use the supplied insulated-tip plugs (or similar plugs) for the voltage measurement.

many of the wiring diagrams show an inductor symbol as the voltage source, suggesting a transformer winding,  using an isolating transformer as the supply seems like a good idea.